# Accessing Navigation Bar Height and Status Bar Height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am currently developing my first iOS application using Swift and I am running into a lot of issues with the UI portion of app development. I have decided to do all of the views programmatically because enough of them are complicated enough that I think storyboarding would be major pain.

My current issue is that I am trying to make all of the spacing on my views relative so that it doesn't matter what the screen size is when it's run. My first issue is spacing from the top down. I know that I have to account for both the Status Bar height and the Navigation Bar height. I know how to access both of these values when I am in a view controller, but I am struggling with where I should store these values.

Do I have to access these values in every view controller where I use them? Do I pass these values to my views through the view controller or should all the framing be done in the view controller? I thought I understood the relationship between view controllers and views, but I'm not totally clear on how things like spacing are handled. Is that on the view controller end or the view?

I know that I can hack this and get it to work, but I am more interested in what the "correct" way of doing this is. An example of a view and view controller that have been programmatically created and work with all devices would be awesome if someone has that available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you don't do 'everything' in code. If you just layout all of your views in code, you could still use the storyboard to manage a single view that is below the navigationbar and the statusbar. Then you would never have to use the actual height of either of them.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make all of the spacing on my views relative so that it doesn't matter what the screen size is when it's run.

The best way to achieve this is to use [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). It can be used in storyboard designer as well as programmatically. It will allow you to define how the UI elements behave without needing to know the dimensions of status bar, tool bar, navigation bar, screen width and height etc.

Comment: Quick additional question: when should I build my own views? It looks like all of the autolayout code goes in the view controller. Have you seen any examples of complicated views created programmatically with autolayout?

Comment: I use auto layout pretty much only in storyboards. I actually think that starting with the visual design would be easier start for you, too. 
For some examples and thorough discussion of auto layout in code, take a look at iOS Auto Layout Demystified book by Erica Sadun.